# Is is possible to use between and like with JSON in mysql / mariadb?

Tags: mysql, mariadb

I have a table name `data` with a column name `body` containing records present in json format i.e.,

```
'{"createdOn": "2018-10-05T00:00:00.000+0000","id":1,"name":"abc"}',
'{"createdOn": "2018-10-06T00:00:00.000+0000","id":2,"name":"xyz"}',
'{"createdOn": "2018-10-10T00:00:00.000+0000","id":3,"name":"aaa"}',
'{"createdOn": "2018-10-25T00:00:00.000+0000","id":4,"name":"qqq"}',
```

I am looking to fetch and delete the records between `"createdOn":"2018-10-05T00:00:00.000+0000"` and `"createdOn":"2018-10-10T00:00:00.000+0000"` for which I am trying to write a query `SELECT * FROM data where body like between '%"createdOn": "2018-10-05%' and '%"createdOn": "2018-10-10%';`  but it is giving the error . How can something like this be achieved ? If anybody can help ?

Thanks

Comment: The result of like operator is a true or false depending on whether the the value matches the pattern. You need regexp_substr() if you want to retrieve a piece of text based on a pattern. Or in this case, some of the json functions can help to get the right value.

Comment: @Shadow thanks to respond .. could you provide me with the statement ?

Comment: How about you try them out first?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can extract values from json and use them in queries:

```
select * from data where JSON_VALUE(body, '$.createdOn') between '2018-10-05T00:00:00.000+0000' and '2018-10-10T00:00:00.000+0000';
select * from data where JSON_VALUE(body, '$.name') LIKE '%a%';
```